# apollo client refetching query not passing variables with react-hooks

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client

I am using a query named PLANTS_QUERY
I am using react hooks. and using use query hook like this

```
 const { loading, error, data, refetch } = useQuery(PLANTS_QUERY);
```

I call refetch function with some variables like this

```
refetch(
  { where: { name_contains: value }}
);
```

it refetches, but it doesn't pass variables to the query,

I console logged the results. when running through the playground it passes variables. but this function provided by hooks doesn't pass variables

this is my query

```
const PLANTS_QUERY = gql`
  query {
    plants{
      plant_name
      is_active
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know if you are using `useQuery` you need to pass the variables to query as a parameter to `useQuery` hook and refetch just execute the original query, if you want change the variables when calling again same query try `useLazyQuery` it gives function that can be used to trigger a query with new variables.

Comment: Apparently you can pass extra vars to refetch, as per the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/) >You can optionally provide a new variables object to the refetch function. If you don't (as is the case in the following example), the query uses the same variables that it used in its previous execution.

Answer (score 0):

although the backend supporting for accepting variables is not enough. changing my gql wrapped query to accepting variables fixed my issue.

```
const PLANTS_QUERY = gql`
  query PlantQuery($where:PlantWhereUniqueInput){
    plants(where:$where){
      plant_name
      is_active
    }
  }
`;
```

now backend is receiving the variables that I'm passing